# Rails enum validation failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, enums

The code below is a simplified version of a polymorphic model that uses enums however I am struggling with the validation.

The last line of the model is the problem validation.

This works:

```
validates_inclusion_of  :value, in: Vote.values.keys
```

This does not work returning an error:

```
validates_inclusion_of  :value, in: vote_options.keys
```

Error

```
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Value is not included in the list
```

Model:

```
class Vote < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :voteable, polymorphic: true

    vote_options  = {vote_no: 0, vote_yes: 1}
    enum value: vote_options

    validates_inclusion_of  :value, in: vote_options.keys
end
```

Update:

```
class Vote < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :voteable, polymorphic: true

    VOTE_OPTIONS  = HashWithIndifferentAccess.new({ vote_no: 0, vote_yes: 1 }).freeze
    EMOJI_OPTIONS = HashWithIndifferentAccess.new({thumb_up: 2, thumb_down: 3, happy_face: 4, sad_face: 5}).freeze

    enum value: HashWithIndifferentAccess.new.merge(VOTE_OPTIONS).merge(EMOJI_OPTIONS)

    validates_inclusion_of  :value, in: vote_options.keys
end
```

Update2:

```
class Like < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :likeable, polymorphic: true

    VOTE_OPTIONS  = { vote_no: 0, vote_yes: 1 }.freeze
    EMOJI_OPTIONS = { thumb_up: 2, thumb_down: 3, happy_face: 4, sad_face: 5 }.freeze

    enum value: VOTE_OPTIONS.merge(EMOJI_OPTIONS)

    with_options :if => :is_meeting? do |o|
        o.validates_uniqueness_of :user_id, scope: [:likeable_id, :likeable_type], message: "You have already voted on this item."
        o.validates_inclusion_of  :value, in: HashWithIndifferentAccess.new(VOTE_OPTIONS).keys
    end

    with_options :if => :is_comment? do |o|
        o.validates_uniqueness_of :user_id, scope: [:likeable_id, :likeable_type], message: "You can only tag once."
        o.validates_inclusion_of  :value, in: HashWithIndifferentAccess.new(EMOJI_OPTIONS).keys
    end

    def is_meeting?
        self.likeable_type == "Meeting"
    end

    def is_comment?
        self.likeable_type == "Comment"
    end

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this behavior is that `enum` [converts](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/5-1-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/enum.rb#L156) the passed-in hash into a [`HashWithIndifferentAccess`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/HashWithIndifferentAccess.html). This is a special ActiveSupport extension to a normal Hash that **treats its symbol and string keys the same**.

Now, your `vote_options` definition uses *symbols* but ActiveRecord internally **uses *strings* when setting enum values** to db record attributes. When validating the record with the `Vote.values.keys` variant, it all works even though it is comparing a string value (in the attribute) to a symbol key in the enum definition, because `Vote.values` will return the *hash with indifferent access* created in the `enum` definition.

On the contrary, if you use `vote_options.keys` for your validation, it will fail because it compares string values with symbols and these are not the same things in Ruby.

To overcome this and still use a class variable (actually, I'd suggest a freezed constant instead here), **use a hash with indifferent access too**:

```
VOTE_OPTIONS = HashWithIndifferentAccess.new({ vote_no: 0, vote_yes: 1 }).freeze
enum value: VOTE_OPTIONS

validates_inclusion_of :value, in: VOTE_OPTIONS.keys
```

**Update** - multiple merged hashes - you only have to declare a HashWithIndifferentAccess where you actually need it, you can use simple hashes in other places:

```
VOTE_OPTIONS  = { vote_no: 0, vote_yes: 1 }.freeze
EMOJI_OPTIONS = { thumb_up: 2, thumb_down: 3, happy_face: 4, sad_face: 5 }.freeze

enum value: VOTE_OPTIONS.merge(EMOJI_OPTIONS)

validates_inclusion_of :value, in: HashWithIndifferentAccess.new(VOTE_OPTIONS).keys
```

Comment: Is my update the correct way to use the merge method? https://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.7/ActiveSupport/HashWithIndifferentAccess/merge

Comment: Generally yes but see my updated answer for a IMO more readable suggestion of hashes declaration and merging. Also, it is not clear to me why you need an enum with values, some of which are invalid? (Note: also fixed the attribute name in my first example.)

Comment: I understand using an enum without values can lead to problems as the ordering is implicit an cannot be changed if new values are added. Which ones are invalid ?

Comment: No, sorry, should have been more explicit, I just wondered why you validate against only a subset (vote options) of all values that can be in the enun attribute?

Comment: I am trialling the idea of using the same polymorphic model for both votes and likes so the validation of available options would depend upon the related model. Not convinced that I should not just use a separate model for each purpose as thee would be potentially 5 functions, I have only shown 2 in update2 above.